# how do i change text format to date in jalali calendar

Tags: php

Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
$date = \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::strftime('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime(
$time->created_at));

$day= \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::convertNumbers($date);

echo $day->format('%A, %d %B %y');
```

The error message is: `Call to a member function format() on string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add a one or two sentences explaining more detailed what you are trying to achieve.
Both $date and $day variables point to strings that do not offer a format function (DateTime objects have a format function).

The convertNumbers is documented as "Convert Latin numbers to persian numbers and vice versa", it simply replaces (other than documented) western arabic numerals with the eastern arabic numeral counterparts.

You could just do the formatting you need as a result in strftime and remove the format call like this.

```
$date = \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::strftime('%A, %d %B %y', strtotime($time->created_at));
$day= \Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::convertNumbers($date);
echo $day;
```